# authorization in requests.Session() not work with Django. I get AnonymousUser

Tags: django, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to create an authorized session using requests.Session() and work with files from the django model.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ('username', 'password')
auth = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/')
file = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/123') #here response is (403 forbidden)
```

In views.py i have check: user.is_authenticated; I always get false (get AnonymousUsers).

How can I log in via requests with session retention to access files?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Shouldn't `session = request.Session()` be `session = requests.Session()`?  If you're using what I *think* you're using, then you missed an extra `s`.  This is different than the regular request in django, without the 's' at the end.

Comment: @R.Uziel , thanks for the answer, I made a mistake when creating a question here, I have "requests" in the code, so the question remains open.

Comment: Okay.  Please add views.py to your question.  Actually, include any models.py, urls.py, and settings.py.  Perhaps the problem is there.